# How to hide my quirestring in Page URL C# MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Register/Register',
    data: formdata,
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    beforeSend: (function (data) {
        $("div.overlay").addClass("show");
        document.getElementById("btnRegSubmit").disabled = true;
    }),
    success: (function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log("Registered successfully.");
        window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Result", "Register")?status=" + data.Status + "&EmailId=" + data.EmailId;
    }),
    error: (function (err) {
        console.error(`Registration failed: ${err}`);
        window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Result", "Register")?status=false";
    })
```

Where `"Result"` is action method and `"Register"` is controller.

Action method needs these to parameter (Status and Emailid) but I am seeing this in URL when pages loads, want hide from end user as URL has email ID.

Comment: I just encoded my parameter values to base64 and decoded inside my action method and it works.